# Retrieve user information from paypal in php using ios sdk

Tags: php, paypal

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/profile_sharing_server.md#profile-sharing-server-side-integration

```
curl 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -H "Authorization: Basic QWZVa...==" \
    -d 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=MFYQ...'
```

What is

```
Authorization: Basic QWZVa...== ??
and retur true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Authorization: Basic xxxx is the OAuth 2 auth token. Basic is the token type, and the xxxx piece is your access token. It's a way of authorizing a user, and will be passed in the headers of a request. More info here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#authentication--headers